# Where to find the EntityList<T> in silverlight ria services?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I can't find any assembly which contains `EntityList<T>` class.

I was reading in old posts that I need a toolkit. But I can't find it because the assembly name has changed. I'm currently using SL5.0.

I'm looking for that object because I need an `ObservableCollection<T>` which supports `EntitySet<T>`. In fact, at the beginning I started using `ObservableCollection<T>` but I realized that it could not update my items.

I've read, `EntityList<T>` is the solution.

Comment: i thought EntityList<T> was renamed to EntitySet<T>

Comment: From here, I've got the information: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Working-with-collections-in-WCF-RIA-Services-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `EntityList<T>` in the *Microsoft.Windows.Data.DomainServices* assembly, which is part of the *WCF RIA Services Toolkit* than can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26939).